# AngularJs for Enterprise application

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, enterprise-architect

Is it preferable to use AngularJs for large and complex enterprise application , which in turn will use Internet Explorer 8 as client.

Comment: So it's partially opinion based. So what? Aren't the opinions and thoughts of our peers helpful to anyone? Another good topic shut down for NOTHING so some SO point hoarders can feel powerful.  But to the OP, here's your answer as of today: "AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8."  So the answer is NO, and that's NOT an opinion. :p

Answer (score 1):

Choosing technology stack for developing applications would be subjective. You may go through various points mentioned on [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) and learn more about AngularJS's IE8 compatibility.